# Drop the file in the particular folder in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. I want to check the error state. If failure, I want to move the file to the error folder. If success, I want to move the file to the success folder.

Example: If number of rows is less than the flat file  is update in the DB it should prompt an error and drop the file in to folder and next file should continue updating in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a For Each Loop that iterates once per file you want to process. By default, this loop's MaximumErrorCount will stop it from iterating after the first failure. Since you want it to still continue on through the other files, set MaximumErrorCount on the loop to 0 (0 = infinity).

Place your data flow inside the loop. Then, attach two File System Tasks to the data flow--one with a precedence constraint of success and the other of failure. If the data flow completes with a success status, the "success" File System Task will run, moving the file to wherever you'd like. If the data flow completes with a failure status, the other File System Task can copy the file to the appropriate failure location.